# how can I mask the mid values in incoming request via xslt

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

how can I mask the mid values in incoming request via xslt. for e.g my incoming request field is

```
<CreditCardNumber>0123456789</CreditCardNumber>
```

and output should be

```
<CreditCardNumber>012**56789</CreditCardNumber> .
```

I am able to achieve using this output

```
<CreditCardNumber>012***56789</CreditCardNumber>
```

via this code

```
<xsl:value-of select="replace(.,substring(.,$length -6 , 2),'*')"/>
```

but the issue is that  it is showing only one masked value for two positions, so how can we make this dynamic ?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "dynamic"? Explain your logic in words, not (only) by example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming "mid values" means the 4th and the 5th character of the input, you could use:

```
<xsl:value-of select="replace(input, '^(.{3}).{2}', '$1**')"/>
```

---

**Note**:

Using `substring()` to identify the portion of the input to mask is problematic.

```
<xsl:value-of select="replace(input, substring(., string-length(.) - 6 , 2),'**')"/>
```

will return the expected `012**56789` result with the given example.

However, when the input is `0123456349`, the result will be `012**56**9`.

---

### Added:

If you want the *start* and the *length* of the mask to be variables, then you could use:

```
<xsl:value-of select="substring(input, 1, $start - 1)"/>
<xsl:value-of select="replace(substring(input, $start, $length), '.', '*')"/>
<xsl:value-of select="substring(input, $start + $length)"/>
```

In such case, it might be worthwhile to turn this into a **function**:

```
<xsl:function name="my:mask">
    <xsl:param name="string" as="xs:string"/> 
    <xsl:param name="start" as="xs:integer"/> 
    <xsl:param name="length" as="xs:integer"/> 
    <xsl:variable name="char" select="'*'"/> 

    <xsl:value-of select="substring($string, 1, $start - 1)"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="replace(substring($string, $start, $length), '.', $char)"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="substring($string, $start + $length)"/>
</xsl:function>
```

Demo: http://xsltransform.net/ncdD7mS/1

---

**XSLT 1.0**

To make this work in XSLT 1.0 (with a suitable processor, such as DataPower), you could use:

```
<xsl:value-of select="substring(input, 1, $start - 1)"/>
<xsl:value-of select="str:padding($length, '*')"/>
<xsl:value-of select="substring(input, $start + $length)"/>
```

or, in pure XSLT 1.0 (assuming the input contains only digits):

```
<xsl:value-of select="substring(input, 1, $start - 1)"/>
<xsl:value-of select="translate(substring(input, $start, $length), '0123456789', '**********')"/>
<xsl:value-of select="substring(input, $start + $length)"/>
```

Comment: Hi Michael, thanks for a quick revert, I tried your input it is working same as my code even though whatever we give it will show only two ** in output. the issue is if I change the (.{3}).{2} to (.{3}).{5} then output should show 5 masked values and not 2. so to make that output dynamic in respect to stars and input we are giving what can be the solution ??

Comment: @AK.DataPower I asked what do you mean by "dynamic". Where will the values come from?

Comment: ---by dynamic I mean, every time we have to increase the **** stars equivalent to the masked value right, is there a way to accommodate the masked value (increasing or decreasing) with single star every time ?????. and it should function in datapower not only in xslt.
currently I am using this <xsl:value-of select="(translate(.,substring(.,$length -6 , 2),'**'),' ',',')"/> and it is working fine in Datapower, but the above issue is still there.